# Save preferences with checkboxes php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to allow users to save their preferences as to what they receive emails for with a set of checkboxes. The code looks like:

```
<label class="checkbox" for="account_updated">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Alerts[]" value="account_updated"  id="account_updated" data-toggle="checkbox">
                            Account Updated
                        </label>

                        <label class="checkbox" for="account_deauthed">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="account_deauthed" name="Alerts[]" id="account_deauthed" data-toggle="checkbox">
                            Account De-authorized
                        </label>

                        <label class="checkbox" for="charge_succeeded">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="charge_succeeded" name="Alerts[]" id="charge_succeeded" data-toggle="checkbox">
                            Charge Succeeded
                        </label>
```

With the PHP looking like:

```
    if(!empty($_POST['Alerts'])) {
                foreach($_POST['Alerts'] as $index) {
                    $index = implode(',', $_POST['Alerts']);
                }
            }
```

My database structure is as follows:

settings table which contains:

```
*setting_id * setting_name     *
*   1       * account.updated  *
*   2       * account.deauthed *
*   *       *                  *
```

etc.

Then a users_to_settings table containing:

```
*user_id * setting_id * setting_value *
* 1      * 0          * 1             *
```

This isn't really working at all and I'm not sure what my best direction is. How should I be storing these preferences?

Thanks!

Comment: If user can have one account and preferences are limited, you can take all these things in one table like this: |userid|account.updated|account.deauthed|

Comment: I was thinking of doing it like that but worried about scaling. I've currently got 32 preferences and although this would be easier, is it the best way?

Comment: So then, according to the my knowledge your design is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the table for users_to_settings to have a new field id that would be the primary key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_to_settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `setting_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `setting_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Try

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id']; // assuming user_id is a hidden input field with the value
$valuesString = "";

if(!empty($_POST['Alerts'])) {
    foreach($_POST['Alerts'] as $selectedOptionIndex => $selectedOptionValue) {
            $valuesString .= "'" . $selectedOptionValue . "',";
    }
}

if ($valuesString != "") {
    $valuesString = substr($valuesString, 0, strlen($valuesString)-1); // removes the ending ,
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT setting_id FROM settings WHERE setting_name IN (".$valuesString.")");
    while($setting = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_to_settings VALUES ('".$user_id."','".$setting['setting_id']."','1')");
    }
}
```

Please note:

```
$_POST['Alerts']
```

always will have those checkbox items that are checked when the form was submitted

Comment: Thanks for this! Gave it a quick run and added error checking to the queries and mysql isn't very happy with it. It's identifying what has been selected in the checkboxes but says that there is a syntax error in the query. Not seeing it myself?

Comment: the settings table name columns have dot(.) instead of underscores(_), try replacing the values. if that doesn't solve it,
can you get the query string using echo and see what it shows? like echo "SELECT setting_id FROM settings WHERE setting_name IN (".$valuesString.")";

Comment: Comes back with this on the first query:                               SELECT setting_id FROM settings WHERE setting_name IN ('account_updated',)

Comment: sorry my bad, replace $valuesString = substr($valuesString, 0, strlen($valuesString)); by $valuesString = substr($valuesString, 0, strlen($valuesString)-1);

updated the answer with the code adjustment

Comment: No worries, that has it correctly identifying and inserting the setting but it only posts one. For instance it will insert that user_id 8 has selected setting_id 1 with a setting_value of 1, despite 5 boxes being selected?

Comment: it works perfectly for me. OK, I guess it is the structure of the users_to_settings table, I think you have user_id is defined as primary key on that table, rather adjust it to have a separate field as id, so change the structure and adjust the code accordingly, I am going to update the answer with those now